# Pandas mask returning wrong values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filtering, mask

I have a dataframe -df- to which I want to apply a series of conditions (masks) and assign a value to a new column.

```
df["CLUSTER"] = 0

s = ((df["gender"]=="M") & (df["age"]>=35) & (df["age"]<=54) & (df["category"]=="A"))
t = ((df["age"]>=18) & (df["age"]<=44) & (df["category"]=="B"))
p = ((df["age"]>=35) & (df["age"]<=54) & (df["category"]=="C"))
pct = ((df["gender"]=="F") & (df["age"]>=18) & (df["age"]<=35) & df["category"]=="A"))
ex = ((df["age"]>55))
s_a = ((df["CLUSTER"]==0)&(df["age"]>=18) & (df["age"]<=54) & (df["category"]=="A")))
s_b = ((df["CLUSTER"]==0)&(df["age"]>=18) & (df["age"]<=54) & (df["category"]=="B")))
s_c = (df["CLUSTER"]==0)&(df["age"]>=18) & (df["age"]<=54) & (df["category"]=="C")))


df.loc[s,"CLUSTER"] = "S" 
df.loc[t,"CLUSTER"] = "T" 
df.loc[p,"CLUSTER"] = "P" 
df.loc[pct,"CLUSTER"] = "PCT" 
df.loc[ex,"CLUSTER"] = "EX"
```

When running the cells above I get

```
df.CLUSTER.value_counts()
0                1121508
PCT               298609
EX                257393
T                 151985
S                  58466
P                  43740
```

And finally, the last three conditions which **explicitly ask for the CLUSTER to be 0** return

```
df.loc[s_a,"CLUSTER"] = "S  A" 
df.loc[s_b,"CLUSTER"] = "S  B"
df.loc[s_c,"CLUSTER"] = "S  C"

df.CLUSTER.value_counts()
S  A         704303
0            683451
E            257393
S  B         174976
S  C         111578
```

I believe it has something to do with the mask actually working with index values, but how can I work around this?

Thanks for reading

Comment: What exactly is incorrect here?

Comment: As you can see, this is very difficult to debug because it's a bit of a mess. What you are doing is basically an `elif` assignment of a column, which should be done using `np.select`. You can clean up the conditions a lot and make it much easier to debug. Parentheses become cluttered in all of these, so you could  make the first condition easier to read: `df['gender'].eq('M') & df['age'].between(35, 54) & df['category'].eq('A')` for instance.

Comment: That being said, after your final three assignments look at `(df[df.CLUSTER.eq(0)].age//1).value_counts()`. I bet you get all people who are younger than 18. None of your masks seem to deal with this situation. (Again if using np.select, the `default` case would capture them)

Comment: @OlegO in regards to your question, at least at first glance, the last three conditions explicitly ask the CLUSTER to be 0, hence should not overwrite any of the previous assigned clusters. Obviously there is something wrong here.

Comment: @ALollz I was actually using np.select, but the default value seemed to overwrite many of the **already assigned** clusters.

Comment: Can you point to the value that seems wrong?